# Utilizar valor que é preenchido após uma Promise

Tags: node.js, axios, async, promises

Galera, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que conforme o código abaixo, busca os dados em uma API e com o resultado dessa, faz outras chamadas e faz um `push` em uma variável, como posso acessar essa variável, somente após terminar todo o laço do `forEach`?

```
    const leagues = ['22537', '22614', '22821', '24320']
    const data = []

    leagues.forEach(async league => {
      const response = await axios(`${api_link}/v2/events/ended?sport_id=1&league_id=${league}&token=${token}&day=20201105`)
      const totalPages = Math.ceil(response.data.pager.total/response.data.pager.per_page)

      for(let i=1; i<=totalPages; i++){
        const response = await axios(`${api_link}/v2/events/ended?sport_id=1&league_id=${league}&token=${token}&day=20201105&page=${i}`)
        const d = response.data.results

        d.forEach(val => {
          data.push(val)
        })
      }
    })

    console.log(data)
```

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui obter sucesso desta forma:

```
const leagues = ['22537', '22614', '22821', '24320']
const data = []
        
const promiseData = leagues.map(async league => {
    const response = await axios(`${api_link}/v2/events/ended?sport_id=1&league_id=${league}&token=${api_token}&day=${actual_date}`)
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(response.data.pager.total/response.data.pager.per_page)
            
    for(let i=1; i<=totalPages; i++){
        const response = await axios(`${api_link}/v2/events/ended?sport_id=1&league_id=${league}&token=${api_token}&day=${actual_date}&page=${i}`)
        const d = response.data.results
                
        d.forEach(val => {
            data.push(val)
        })
    }
})
        
await Promise.all(promiseData)
```